# Extra margin within 100% width flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, material-design, appbar

I'd like to make a appbar following the material design.

[image]

The code I write trying to use flexbox with 100% width to draw this.

```
.appbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;

  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;

  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.46);
}
```

But I get a extra margin within my appbar. Why is it happened?

[image]

Comment: Try `body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}`

Comment: `body` has margin by default

Comment: In most major browsers, the default margin is 8px on all sides. It is defined in pixels by the user-agent-stylesheet your browser provides. So you need to remove the margin from body.

Comment: I have not think about the default body tag, my false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add     `margin: 0;`
    `padding: 0;` to `body`

```css
 body{
  margin: 0;
padding: 0;
 }
 .appbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;

  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;

  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.46);
}
```

```html
<div class="appbar"></div>
```